# Calculating total price of items in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, subtotal

I use the volley library and load json from the server and display it in recyclerview. I want to create a shopping cart and calculate the total price of the recyclerview items. My problem is that the total cost of the items is not calculated.
Help me please

This is my code:

```
public class checkout extends AppCompatActivity {
    String shop = SHOP;
    List<Product6> productList6;
    ProductsAdapter6 productsAdapter6;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ProductsAdapter6 adapter6;

    private GridLayoutManager layoutManager;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager RecyclerViewLayoutManager;
    private TextView subTotal;
    private double mSubTotal = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(RecyclerViewLayoutManager);
        adschild2();

        productList6 = new ArrayList<>();

        subTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub_total);

        mSubTotal = grandTotal(productList6);
        subTotal.setText(String.valueOf(mSubTotal));

    }

    private int grandTotal(List<Product6> items) {

        int totalPrice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            totalPrice += items.get(i).getBack();
        }

        return totalPrice;
    }

    private void adschild2() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, shop, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    // converting the string to json array object
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                    // traversing through all the object
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        // getting product object from json array
                        JSONObject product6 = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        // adding the product to product list
                        productList6.add(new Product6(product6.getInt("id"), product6.getDouble("back")));

                    }
                    // creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                    ProductsAdapter6 adapter6 = new ProductsAdapter6(checkout.this, productList6);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter6);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        // adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) And you also may want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to

```
mSubTotal = grandTotal(productList6);
```

should be inside your call for

```
adschild2()
```

in onResponse  - after you parsed the JSON.

the reason is that adschild2 is an asynchronous function that populates productList6 only after onResponse is invoked, while the call for grandTotal is synchronous and calculating the sum of an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this in your adapter class and call adapter.getGrandTotal() from activity

```
public List<Product6> mItems = new ArrayList()

public void setData(List<Product6> items) {
    this.mItems = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

private int grandTotal() {
    int totalPrice = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
        totalPrice += mItems.get(i).getBack();
    }
    return totalPrice;
}

/* onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder remains same */
```

As per the comments, please find the modified classes

```
package com.example.pix.shoping;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie> moviesList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText(movie.getYear() + "");
    }

    public void setData(List<Movie> items) {
        this.moviesList = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int grandTotal() {
        int totalPrice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < moviesList.size(); i++) {
            totalPrice += moviesList.get(i).getYear();
        }
        return totalPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.pix.shoping;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView subTotal;
    private double mSubTotal = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        prepareMovieData();


        subTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub_total);

        // This whould be called on a user action mostly like a button click
        mSubTotal = mAdapter.grandTotal();
        subTotal.setText("ØªÙˆÙ…" + String.valueOf(mSubTotal) + " Ù‚ÛŒÙ…Øª Ú©Ù„");
    }

    /**
     * Prepares sample data to provide data set to adapter
     */
    private void prepareMovieData() {
        Movie movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", 2015);
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", 2015);
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "Action", 2015);
        movieList.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie("Shaun the Sheep", "Animation", 2015);
        movieList.add(movie);

        // notify adapter about data set changes
        // so that it will render the list with new data
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How to call in activity?

Comment: adapter.getGrandTota()

Comment: this is my adapter please help me
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Product6 product6 = productList6.get(position);
        //loading the image
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product6.getBack()));

        
    }


    private int grandTotal(List<Product6> items){

        int totalPrice = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
            totalPrice += items.get(i).getBack();
        }

        return totalPrice;
    }

Comment: I can not replace if you can do this??

Address files :
185.4.31.183/ProductsAdapter6.java
185.4.31.183/checkout.java

Comment: MAde the changes to answer

Comment: error: method grandTotal in class ProductsAdapter6 cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: List<Product6>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Fixed it. try now.

Comment: stoped:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void pixdesign.sfeorginal.parim.ProductsAdapter6.setData(java.util.List)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please try again.  if you still face it, please share the project zip file. Will try and update you

Comment: Hello
I changed the code
And I will display the information offline
Please try again

Zip url ; https://uploadfiles.io/omiap

Comment: How to change the adapter, how is it correct?
this is my adapter Movie :https://ufile.io/5bnsk

Comment: Can you clearly tell me what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It should be int

Comment: Great. Good luck